# create start and end date columns seperately from a single date column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the date columns contains two dates of all the `DepartmentID`, one is `start_date` and another one is `end_date`. The output will have two columns for start and end date. I want to implement using SQL window function or Spark Dataframe.

Input

```
Employee ID      Date           DepartmentID    SupervisorID
10001            20130101          001             10009
10001            20130909          001             10019
10001            20131201          002             10018
10001            20140501          002             10017
10001            20141001          003             10015
10001            20141201          003             10014
```

Expected Output

```
Employee ID    DateStart    DateEnd      DepartmentID
10001         20130101      20131201       001
10001         20131201      20141001       002
10001         20141001       Null          003
```

Comment: Are there exactly 2 rows per department for each employee?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you register the dataframe as a temporary view named 'tmp', and run the following SQL to get the expected result.

```
    select EmployeeID,DateStart,
        lead(DateStart) over (order by DateStart) DateEnd,DepartmentID
    from
        (select EmployeeID,min(Date) DateStart,DepartmentID
        from tmp
        group by EmployeeID,DepartmentID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `DateEnd` for Department 003 is `Null`. It should be `20141201` from my understanding of your problem. Here is a scala version using a group by and an aggregation. The min is the starting date, the max the end date and we set the end to null in case there is only one row.

```scala
df
    .groupBy("DepartmentID", "Employee ID")
    .agg(min('Date) as "DateStart", max('Date) as "DateEnd", count('*) as "count")
    .withColumn("DateEnd", when('count > 1, 'DateEnd))
    .drop("count").show(false)
+------------+-----------+---------+--------+
|DepartmentID|Employee ID|DateStart|DateEnd |
+------------+-----------+---------+--------+
|002         |10001      |20131201 |20140501|
|003         |10001      |20141001 |20141201|
|001         |10001      |20130101 |20130909|
+------------+-----------+---------+--------+
```